# How can I parse a timestamp that is using the incorrect number of digits for seconds?

Tags: java, timestamp, java-11, timestamp-with-timezone

Long story short, someone messed up a few months ago, and the Production environment is saving timestamps on certain cases, where the timestamp format as `MMM-dd-yy HH:mm:sss'Z'` Yes that is 3 digits for the seconds, NOT milliseconds.

How can I get DateTimeFormatter to be able to parse such as a timestamp, as attempting to use that pattern above is not a valid pattern for it to use?

Comment: Could you modify the string before passing it to DateTimeFormatter?

Comment: What values do the three seconds have? Is the first one always zero (e.g. `043` - > 43 seconds), or is it something significant that would need to be converted (e.g. `119` -> 1 minute 59 seconds)?

Comment: Why is the `Z` escaped at the end? Do you want to always append a `Z`? If you know *someone messed up a few months ago*, do you also know what he messed up? How is the timestamp produced? What formatter did it use?

Comment: You could *cheat* by making the third `s` upper case (`S`). That may at least parse the `String`. Maybe try that.

Comment: @CrushaK.Rool, all of them starts with 0 on the first second digit as far as I can tell.

Comment: @deHaar, Ya they hardcoded the Z  in for a 0 UTC offset but formatted it as a timestamp for a different TZ, I already know how to address that part so it wasn't originally part of this question. They used a formatter from jslt that is embedded in a J-Easy flow activity.

Comment: Since the first digit of your 3 digits seconds will always be 0 (zero), you can use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-dd-yy HH:mm:0ssX", Locale.ROOT)`. Replace the locale with the one used when formatting.

Comment: The other option is `MMM-dd-yy HH:mm:sX` (just one `s`). One pattern letter for a numeric field accepts more digits -- apparently even three digits for seconds even though it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just use a regex to preprocess the input date before sending it to the formatter?

The following regex captures all the data except for the extraneous second:

```
([a-zA-Z]{3})-(\d\d)-(\d\d) (\d\d):(\d\d):\d(\d\d)(.*)
```

And this replacement string puts it back together:

```
$1-$2-$3 $4:$5:$6$7
```